# After being unplugged when I turn on computer it quickly turns off and back on again

Tags: windows-10, boot, desktop-computer

I have a desktop that I leave on and plugged in 95% of the time. But lately I have noticed that if I turn it off and unplug it/flip the switch on the power supply, when I turn it back on it powers on for a second, then shuts down, then powers right back up normally.

When it first powers on it doesn't seem to get into POST, I don't hear any beeps or codes, and it is only on for maybe a second or two.

When it immediately powers back on it goes through POST, I get the single beep and then it boots up.

This is the only thing that is "off" about the PC. It runs great and I have never had any problems.

I doubt this is normal behavior, what could be going on?

Comment: This doesn’t necessarily indicate a problem.  There are motherboards where this would be totally normal

Comment: @Ramhound I have never heard of that before, does it serve a purpose?

Comment: It’s just how the motherboard works.

Comment: It may be the power button (not a real switch) or the Power Supply circuit that manages the button. That seems like a realistic starting point to test.

Comment: If the PC is a bit older it might be that the BIOS battery is empty. When you start the PC it detects that the BIOS settings are not set, loads the default values and then restarts to apply them. When changing BIOS settings is is not uncommon that the PC completely powers off and some seconds later restores power to finally boot.

Comment: @Robert your comment turned out to be the issue, if you write an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PC is a bit older it might be that the BIOS battery is empty:

When you start the PC it detects that the BIOS settings are not set and the PC is loading the default values and then restarts to apply them.

When changing BIOS settings is is not uncommon that after saving BIOS settings, the PC completely powers off and some seconds later restores power to finally boot with all the new settings active.

I assume this behavior is because some BIOS settings are only applied on a cold boot, or the mainboard manufacturer want to make sure that all components are reset.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this feature in some Dell and Lenevo desktop mechines. There is a BIOS feature called Wake-on-AC-Power or Wake-on-AC or similar names that tells the machine to automatically boot up if the power goes from off to on. The initial start up should be there for checking these situations with the BIOS and then get commands from BIOS to proceed with a bootup or keep the machine off.

Comment: That feature (I use Lenovo desktops myself and at customers) does not cause the double startup described) . I have not seen BIOS Wake on something turned on in recent Lenovo machines.

Comment: Yeah they probably changed this feature in recent machines. Those machines that I mentioned were at least 8-10 years old. I think the lenovo ones were called ThinkCenter.